# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'describe'

Tags: python-3.x, class, attributeerror

```py
class Computer:

    def _inti_(self, storage, color , system):
        no_of_Computer = 0
        self.storage = storage
        self.color = color
        self.system = system
        Computer.no_of_Computer +=1

    def describe (self):

        print(f'my storage is {self.storage} and my color is{self.color} and my system is {self.system}')

Computer_1 = ("1TB ,  silver , windows ")

Computer_2 = (" 4TB , black , linux")

Computer_3 = (" 9TB , white ,mac ")

Computer_1.describe()
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: First, initiate the class properly, use ```__init__``` and try again

Answer (score 1):

`Computer_1`, `Computer_2` and `Computer_3` aren't `Computer` instances, they are just strings (surrounded by parentheses). You need to call the `Compueter`'s constructor to create new instances of it. Also, note that each argument should be its own string, not a single string with commas in it.
Additionally, note that a constructor is defined by the method `__init__` (note the double undescores), not `_inti_`:

```py
class Computer:

    def __init__(self, storage, color , system):
        no_of_Computer = 0
        self.storage = storage
        self.color = color
        self.system = system
        Computer.no_of_Computer +=1

    def describe (self):

        print(f'my storage is {self.storage} and my color is{self.color} and my system is {self.system}')

Computer_1 = Computer("1TB", "silver", "windows")

Computer_2 = Computer("4TB", "black", "linux")

Computer_3 = Computer("9TB", "white", "mac")

Computer_1.describe()
```

Comment: i think that `no_of_Computer = 0` should be outside `__init__`

Comment: @diggusbickus You're probably right, but it's immaterial to **this** question, so I just copied it as-is from the OP's code.